# Favicon overwritten by Firewall favicon since https

Tags: html, firewall, favicon

On my site, all worked fine with the favicon. Since i switched to https (using DNAT Rules on Astaro Firewall) it displays the Astaro-Favicon. I dont want to change the FW's favicon and can't find any information how to solve this.

I include the icon using

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon">
<link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Comment: Did you try linking to a file located in another place (not in /) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of linking to the default location, often overwritten, a solution is to put your icon in another location and link to that location.

Note also that absolute URL (URL starting with a `/`) are dangerous since they stop being relevant as soon as you move your site to a subdirectory (and the user may see an different path than you, especially if you use a proxy).